# How to make a database transaction with Room using functions from differents DAOs and using coroutines?

Tags: android, database, transactions, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I want to make a database transaction with Room using functions from different Daos using coroutines.

If I use `@Transaction` annotation I can only use the functions from the same DAO. If I use the Room database function `runInTransaction` I can't use coroutines.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a suspend extension function for this `withTransaction()`. Check this out:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/room/ktx/src/main/java/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.kt